# Accessing child collection in MVC5 razow views from model

Tags: razor, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-2.0

I am currently having an issue trying to gain access to child collections within my models.

My model looks like the following(please bear in mind i have stripped a lot of values out, my model is not that small):

```
public class Games
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ICollection<GameDetails> Details { get; set; }
}
```

Now i can easily grab the data in my controller using a simple linq query and including the child data(in this case 'details').

I am however struggling to see how i can access this data both for posting, and for reading it when it is passed back to my view.

My view looks like this:

```
<dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
    </dt>
    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Title)
    </dd>
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Details)
    </dt>
    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Details)
    </dd>
```

But it does not seem that i can access the data that is inside the child collection.

I have tried model.Details. but i cant access the data in the child collection.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the problem relies on the usage of `List` instead of `ICollection`.

- Reading: you can use `@foreach` or `@for()` to iterate the items in the collection.
- Posting: this is when using `@foreach` with `HtmlHelper` or `TagHelper` to generate inputs inside the form won't work because `@foreach` will result identical IDs for those inputs. Hence you have to use `@for()` with index.

I also see you used `@Html.DisplayFor()`. I assume you know what you're doing. `@Html.DisplayFor()` will render the templates called `DisplayTemplates` that match the property's type.

For example, assuming the property `Title` is a `String`, if you have defined a View called `String.cshtml` inside `DisplayTemplates` folder of the view, calling `@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Title)` will use that template to render for that property.

**String.cshtml**

```
@model string

@if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model))
{
    <!-- You can render different HTML elements here -->
}
else
{
    <!-- You can render different HTML elements here -->
}
```

I normally don't use `@Html.DisplayFor()` for building form elements. Instead, I would just use specific HTML helpers or tag helpers to build specific input types. For example, to build text boxes, use `@Html.TextBoxFor()` or `<input type="text" asp-for="xxx" />`. To build text areas, use `@Html.TextAreaFor()` or `<textarea asp-for="xxx"></textarea>`.

I just like to explicitly declare/define input elements.

**Sample form using tag helper (wrote by hand, not tested):**

```
@model Games

<!-- asp-area, asp-controller, asp-action are tag helpers on the form -->
<form asp-area="" asp-controller="game" asp-action="manage">
    <!-- hidden type input for the Id? -->
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
    <dl>
        <dt>
            <label asp-for="Title"></label>
        </dt>
        <dd>
            <input type="text" asp-for="Title" />
        </dd>
        <dt>
            <label asp-for="Details"></label>
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @for(int i = 0; i < Model.Details.Count(); i++)
            {
                <label asp-for="Details[i].MakeUpProperty1"></label>

                <!-- textbox for property 1? -->
                <input type="text" asp-for="Details[i].MakeUpProperty1" />

                <label asp-for="Details[i].MakeUpProperty2"></label>

                <!-- number type input box for property 2? -->
                <input type="number" asp-for="Details[i].MakeUpProperty2" />

                <!-- dropdown for property 3? -->
                <select asp-for="Details[i].MakeUpProperty3"
                    asp-items="Model.AvailableProperty3List.ToSelectListItem()" ></select>              
            }
        </dd>
    </dl>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a @for loop with a list

```
@for (int i = 0; i < model.Details.Count(); i++)
{
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Details[i].Title)
    </dt>
    ...
}
```

It would be better to use a List in your model, rather than an ICollection - so the view-model contains the definitive list of items to be displayed.